# query to get start time and end time from same column based on boolean value order by primary key

Tags: sql-server, query, timestamp

[image: data from database]

[image: Expected results:]

As of now, this is my current query:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN [timestamp] END) as machineOn
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN [timestamp] END) as machineOff

FROM machine_table
where machineno='mc202101-123'
group by machineno, timestamp order by timestamp desc
```

Comment: Howdy! Welcome to the site. Please take a look at [this post](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/52344). To help us help you, we'd need the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the two tables and some example data (as inserts, not screenshots!), as well as a description of what you're trying to do. From just the two screenshots, it's not entirely clear what your objective is.

Comment: Please construct your questions based on the details in [mcve].   Adding table DDL statements, sample DML statements, and providing desired output via a markup table as shown in the example makes it easier for us to provide great answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with window functions alone, no grouping needed.

```
WITH NextValue AS
(
    SELECT *,
      LEAD(status, 1, -1) OVER (ORDER BY [timestamp]) AS NextStatus
    FROM machine_table
    WHERE machineno = 'mc202101-123'
),
Filtered AS (
    SELECT *,
      LEAD([timestamp]) OVER (ORDER BY [timestamp]) AS NextTimestamp 
    FROM NextValue
    WHERE NextStatus <> Status
)
SELECT
  [timestamp] AS machineOn,
  NextTimestamp AS machineOff
FROM Filtered
WHERE Status = 1
ORDER BY
  timestamp DESC;
```

If you want to do this for every `machineno` then change each `OVER` clause to

```
OVER (PARTITION BY machineno ORDER BY [timestamp])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It helps a lot.